# Ajax post not completely working in IE8

Tags: javascript, ajax, regex, internet-explorer-8

I have a simple post that works with every other browser but IE version 8.

```
        $.post(             
        "/pages/event_layout",
        { id: id },
        function(html){
            $('#the_content').html(html);
        },
        'html'        
        );
```

I realized that the issue is this:[image]

When it posts and retrieves data, there is a space at the beginning of the content resulting in basically nothing appearing, or the good old *Text-Empty Text Node* issue with IE8 because Microsoft is awesome.

so on the post I have tried this to get rid of the initial space.

```
        $.post(             
        "/pages/event_layout",
        { id: id },
        function(html){
            $('#the_content').html($.trim(html));
        },
        'html'        
        );
```

but no avail. Is there REGEX or something I can use to eliminate this space and is also compliant with IE8.

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: Just to make sure that's the problem: when you remove the space (server side, or using a test static php page), the content is shown correctly?

Comment: Are you sure it is a space and not some special character that just appears visibly as a space?

Comment: its actually pulling from another page. The basis of what I am working on is an MVC like structure. Im pulling from a partial view, and in this partial view there is no space in front of the div in the html. Seems like it is phantom. Maybe it is a special character, no idea. But I'm certain it would resolve the issue. As I have another post retrieving information elsewhere and is working 100%.

Comment: Does $.parseHTML instead of $.trim help? (jQuery 1.8+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to provide the correct answer without the AJAX call result. Here is the regex that will trim any white-space characters from the HTML beginning:

```
function(html){
  $('#the_content').html(html.replace(/^\s+/, ""));
},
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eR1gC5/2)

Comment: Well, it got rid of the Text-Empty Text Node situation, but getting rid of that didn't solve the issue I thought it would have.According to the post, it posts all the data I want, but only a certain amount of the data is being written. I'm lost on the cause of why only some of the data is being written,

Comment: figured it out. Had one too many closing divs in my partial view and threw things off, but without a doubt this still helped achieve the fix. Thanks